# how to get different unique names

Tags: php

I need to rename a lot of images in a folder i.e. give them unique names.

```
$path = "../images/";
$items = glob($path . '*.jpg');
foreach($items as $img) { 

$old = substr($img, 3);
$new = 'images/' . uniqid() . '.jpg'; 
echo $new . '<br>';
```

Result - all `$new` variables are the same - `images/58fee748d3c93.jpg`

How to get different unique names?

Comment: Maybe you could use PHPs [rand](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function.

Comment: @JasonJoslin, try my code pls, and you can see - there is no unique names. All names are identicall.

Comment: @bonaca interesting question! Made me curious as to why uniqid() is not generating a unique id and I found this guys post. Only posting in-case you or others were curious like me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29974344/6208463

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `md5(date('dmyhis')).'.jpg';`
or

```
 md5(date('dmy').uniqid().date('his')).'.jpg';`
```

this would make it more unique and make it look random

**EDIT**

```
md5(date('dmy').rand(10).date('his')).rand(0,15).'.jpg';`
```

Comment: This would seem perfect answer as md5 creates ramdom strings added with two dates and uniqid().

Comment: please try - all `$new` variables are identicall again.

Comment: ohh your using it  inside a loop my bad `md5(rand(10).rand(10).date('his')).'.jpg';`

Answer (score 3):

try adding rand() in unique id like

```
uniqid(rand())
```

works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

```
what about like this you have have images name that can access easily.
$path = "../images/";
$items = glob($path . '*.jpg');
$name="any-good-name-";
$counter=0;
foreach($items as $img) { 
$old = substr($img, 3);
$new = 'images/'.$name.$counter'.jpg'; 
echo $new . '<br>';
$counter++;
}
```

Comment: nice but it's not solution for me, because later I need upload another images in the same folder and need to give them unique name too.

Comment: $name=uniqid()."-any-good-name-"; then you can try this this will be more simple thing then any one